# Python function that outputs the name of the column rather than the value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to get python to output the name of columns in a dataframe rather than a value. I want the function to create a new column that lists the name of the highest column for each row. Similar to what I have below but instead of outputting the value I'd like it to output the name of the column instead.

```
df['name'] = np.max(df, axis = 1))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `df.idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: doesn't `df.columns` work?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma that worked great, thanks!

Comment: Now I see what you meant.  You wanted the new column to contain the names of the column containing the highest value in that row.  Got it.